# Como usar Vetores para instânciação em JAVA?

Tags: java

Olá, estou fazendo um jogo de perguntas e respostas em java e estou tendo problemas com a instânciação de multiplus jogadores(Objeto).

Gostaria de saber com é possível usar vetores para criação de multiplus jogadores(Objetos), como acessar e modificar os valores do atributos presentes na classe. Alguém poderia me dar essa luz?

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde Herbet,

Você poderia criar um `array` com o tipo da classe que representa o jogador e ir salvando nele

```
Player[] players = new Player[100];
         players[0] = player;
```

Para recuperar/modificar os objetos você precisará saber em que posição o objeto está, o que já é um problema, e acessar as propriedades do objeto da seguinte forma

```
long scores = players[0].getScores();
              player[10].setLife(10);

// Outra forma com variáveis
Player player45 = player[45];
       player45.setDecreaseslife(34);
```

Imagine que você não faça ideia de em qual posição o player está, para encontrá-lo você poderia fazer algo como

```
for(int i = 0; i < players.lenght; i++) {
    /* Compare uma informação previamente conhecida */
}
```

Mas isso não é tão escalável, imagine que você tenha um `array` de 2000 players... Mas é lógico que esses detalhes são relativos a cada projeto.

Também temos o problema lá do início: o dimensionamento. Em Java, `array`s são estruturas imutáveis. Isso significa na prática que, se você define seu `array` com `n` posições, e acontecer de apenas um quantidade muito menor que `n` de objetos ocuparem o `array`, você terá um objeto na memória com um tamanho que ele verdadeiramente não necessita. Ou também pode acontecer o contrário, onde você define `n` posições e tentar salvar em uma posição fora da faixa de `n` [o tamanho do `array` é de 0 à `n-1` em Java], então prepare-se para receber um erro informando que não há mais espaço. Uma opção seria copiar o `array`para outro e incrementar o tamanho, o que provavelmente não será nada legal para o desempenho. Aconselho estudar outra estrutura, veja os tipos de lista disponíveis no Java e escolha a que melhor se encaixa no seu problema.

Answer (score 0):

O amigo utilizou `array`, eu usaria um `list`, o crescimento ocorre de acordo com a necessidade, no caso era só fazer algo semelhante a isso:

```
ArrayList<Jogadores> jogadores = new ArrayList<Jogador>();
Jogador j1 = new Jogador();
jogadores.add(j1);
// faz a sua manipulação
jogadores.get(0).getPontuacao();
// caso queira andar pelo array
for(Jogador j : jogadores) {
// faça sua manipulação com todos os jogadores...
}
```